# R ggmap calculate nautical distance

Tags: r, ggmap

I would like to calculate the "nautical" distance between locations. ggmap can return the distances by car and train, but is there a way to get the distance that a ship is taking?

My Code:

```
library(ggmap)
mapdist(from = "Los Angeles", to="New York")
mapdist(from = "Los Angeles", to="Shanghai")

    from       to       m       km    miles seconds  minutes    hours
1 Los Angeles New York 4489031 4489.031 2789.484  143866 2397.767 39.96278

     from       to km miles minutes hours
1 Los Angeles Shanghai NA    NA      NA    NA
```

Comment: You may want to check the geosphere package, it should have the functions you are looking for.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "distance that a ship is taking". simply calculating great circle distance across an uninterrupted body of water is simple enough - geosphere will help you out. But if you want to take into account best route navigating around land masses, using or not using shipping canals, accounting for weather conditions, tides, avoiding piracy hotspots... then it is too complex I doubt you get an easy solution

Comment: http://www.sea-distances.org/ has a calculator for this. Maybe you scrape the results from them?

Comment: See [Distance calculator between ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575364/distance-calculator-between-the-ports).